# Is it possible to call Database.executeBatch from a For loop

Tags: apex, batch

I am processing hundreds of thousands of call records that must be assigned to their respective telephone lines based on the phone number. I wanted to retrieve a list of Phone Line records and then create multiple batch jobs to find all related telephone call records.

```
    public void GetLines(){

            List<Lines__c> lines = [Select id, phone_number__c from lines__c ORDER BY Line_Status__c ASC];

            for(Lines__c l: lines){
                       ExecuteBatchUpdate(l.id, l.phone_number__c );         
            }  
        }

    public void ExecuteBatchUpdate(Id lineid, String phone){
    ..
    If(Test.isRunningTest()){
                Id batchInstanceId = Database.executeBatch(new BatchUpdateCallRecordsAssingLine(q, Lineid), 20); 
                System.abortJob(batchInstanceId);
            }else{
                    Database.executeBatch(new BatchUpdateCallRecordsAssingLine(q, Lineid));
            }
    ..
    }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Detailed_Call_Data__c> scope){

    List <Detailed_Call_Data__c> callsData = new List<Detailed_Call_Data__c>();

    for (Detailed_Call_Data__c callrec : scope) {
        Detailed_Call_Data__c rectoupdate = new Detailed_Call_Data__c();
        rectoupdate.id = callrec.id;
        rectoupdate.Line__c = lineId; 

        callsData.add(rectoupdate);
    }
    update callsData;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151.

Is it possible to call Database.executeBatch from a loop?  If not, what is the right way do deal with this scenario?

Comment: have each batch finish() invoke the next batch

Comment: What are the batches doing? Calling a batch with a single record input is not an ideal use case most of the time.

Comment: the batch picks up thousands of Phone Call records and adds a relationship with a matching line based on the phone number. there are 12K Lines and thousands of call records.

Comment: @cropredy could you pls elaborate?

Comment: i'm with David - why not execute a single batch where the start method does the query on `Lines__c`?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your batch class code. My initial thought is why not execute one batch and have the batch do the query you're doing in getLines?

Comment: @cropredy & David, would you be able to demonstrate what you have in mind?

here is the batch:

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Call_Data__c> scope){
      
        List <Call_Data__c> callsData = new List<Call_Data__c>();
        
        for (Call_Data__c callrec : scope) {
            Call_Data__c rectoupdate = new Call_Data__c();
            rectoupdate.id = callrec.id;
            rectoupdate.Line__c = lineId; 
                 
            callsData.add(rectoupdate);
            
      }
        update callsData;
    }

Comment: please use [edit] and post the above comment as formatted code - comments aren't the place for code

Comment: done. and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be shortchanging yourself on the power of Batch Apex.

My understanding is this. You've got some records in `Lines__c`, at high volume (12K), and many more records in `Detailed_Call_Data__c` (hundreds of thousands).

The purpose of your batch job is to link up (based on a phone number, which I really hope is an indexed field) the `Detailed_Call_Data__c` records to their corresponding `Lines__c`.

Running a batch job for each `Lines__c` is not going to be the most efficient way to do this. (For one thing, you'll hit the Apex Flex Queue limit really fast). Instead, I see a couple of viable options, which are not mutually exclusive.

### Scheduled Incremental Update Batch

Run a batch on the `Detailed_Call_Data__c` every night.

Have it query for only records that aren't associated with a `Lines__c` already.

In `execute()`, collect the identifiers (phone numbers) for that batch of `Detailed_Call_Data__c`. Query for the matching `Lines__c` and build a `Map<String, Lines__c>` to collate the numbers to the lines. Then, iterate over the `Detailed_Call_Data__c` again, and populate the relationships to those `Lines__c` that were located.

### Group Incoming `Lines__c` in Each Batch Job

Keep your current approach, except instead of passing a single `Lines__c` into your batch, pass a `List<Lines__c>`. In `start()`, collect the phone numbers of those `Lines__c` records and run a query for `Detailed_Call_Data__c` that matches *any* of them.

In `execute()`, build a `Map<String, Lines__c>` to collate the numbers to the lines. Then, iterate over your scope of `Detailed_Call_Data__c` records and assign each to the matching `Lines__c`.

### Summary

Either way (or both), you'll massively reduce the number of Apex batch jobs you're running, and will likely get much better performance out of it.

Comment: David, many thanks for sharing your knowledge. Your detailed explanation is exactly what I needed.  Thanks to all the contributors!