# Database.executebatch call in for loop causing Codescan warnings

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, database

I have a piece of code that is causing some codescan warnings and it is not liking the database.executebatch in the for loop. The thing is I am not sure to go around it

My code:

```
 public with sharing class Mustard extends ApplicationSObjectDomain {
    public Mustard(List<Mustard__c> sObjectList) {
        super(sObjectList);
    }
    public class Constructor implements fflib_SObjectDomain.IConstructable {
    public fflib_SObjectDomain construct(List<sObject> sObjectList) {
        return new Mustard(sObjectList);
    }
    }
    public override void onAfterUpdate(Map<Id,SObject> existingRecords)
    {
        try
        {
            launchJob(existingRecords);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            //error handling
        }
    }
    
    public void launchJob(Map<Id,SObject> oldRecMap){
        Mustard__c oldRec = Null;
        if(records != Null) {
            for(Mustard__c rec:(List<Mustard__c>) records) {
                oldRec = (Mustard__c) oldRecMap.get(rec.Id);
                if(rec.Job_Status__c != oldRec.Job_Status__c & String.isNotBlank(rec.Async_Class_Name__c)
                   & 'on'.equalsIgnoreCase(rec.Job_Status__c)) {
                    Type classType = Type.forName(rec.Async_Class_Name__c);
                    if(classType.newInstance() instanceof Queueable & !System.isQueueable()) {
                        Queueable batchName = (Queueable)classType.newInstance();
                        system.enqueueJob(batchName);
                    } else if(classType.newInstance() instanceof Database.Batchable<sObject>) {
                        Database.Batchable<sObject> batchName = (Database.Batchable<sObject>)classType.newInstance();
                        String jobID;
                        if(rec.Batch_Size__c!=Null) {
//problem with below statement
                            jobID = Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<sObject>)batchName,rec.Batch_Size__c.intValue());
                        } else { 
//problem with below statement
                            jobID = Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<sObject>)batchName, 25); 
                        }
                        //exception loging for flex queue locking
                        if( jobID.startsWith('000') ) { //000xxxxxxxxxxxx should be returned when Batch job fails to acquire lock.
                            //FAILED CASE SCENARIO
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
```

I saw [Is it possible to call Database.executeBatch from a For loop](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283396/is-it-possible-to-call-database-executebatch-from-a-for-loop) also and not sure how I can apply some type of bulkification considering I am doing processing on the subsequent job ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in your code.

1. There can only be 5 running Batch Job in an org concurrently and rest 100 goes to flex queue. So in a single transaction you can trigger max 105 `Database.executeBatch`(if no batch is running in org at that instance). 5 of which will go to concurrent running queue, rest will go to flex queue (as applicable).
2. When you call batches from trigger, there is always a possibility that there are more than 105 records being inserted. As trigger runs in batch of 200. So your execution will fail.
3. 101 SOQL error, **is not coming because of `Database.executeBatch`**, it mush be coming because of whats happening inside that running batch instance. My guess is, it might be trying to insert or update in bulk and the triggers on those object is throwing the exception.
4. It is always a good idea to check the limits before you insert those in org.
   `SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status =:BATCH_HOLDING_STATUS`. If there a value returned from this aggregated query which is more than 0, then execute `Database.executeBatch` else add it to an object and run a scheduled job on top of those objects. So that you are sure that the configured job is never missed.

You may need to use a GateKeeper framework. Google it, you will get tons

5. I see you have added `Queueable` too. In a single transaction you can only trigger 50 Queueable job. So it may fail in future.

Comment: My sincere apologies. I had meant to say code scan errors. It was not SOQL 101 but codescan says it is not good practice as it may cause SOQL 101

Comment: In that case, if you are sure, your triggers wont run in batch of 200 and runs less than 50 always, then mark it as false positive. My suggestion would be to change the design as suggested above. Run a scheduled job on `Mustard` object and call Batch or Queueable, as per a framework, after querying 50 chunk. And mark `Mustard` record as `Processed` once it is successfully processed, so that next scheduled job wont pick the record again.